# Tool tip is not visible when using TextField widget as a child

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a text field which is going to take a password as an input and it must show what are the limited character someone can enter ex: see the given image. I tried using tooltip widget but it is not working on textfield .
 [image]